# why main thread is also call the thread pool's execute() method?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am testing the **ThreadPoolExecutor**. I print out some debug info in the customized ThreadPoolExecutor's **execute()** method. The **execute()** method is called by an instance of the customized **ThreadPoolExecutor**. When I look at the print out, I found there are some duplicated print out which is from the **main thread**. I am wondering why the **main** **thread** calls the customized ThreadPoolExecutor's execute() method? The runnable code is attached here:

----------Thead: main/1
[PoolSize/CorePoolSize] [1/2]

----------Thead: pool-1-thread-1/11
[PoolSize/CorePoolSize] [1/2]

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class MyThreadPoolExecutorTest2
{
    private List<MyRunnable> myRunnables = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new MyThreadPoolExecutorTest2().test();
    }

    public void test()
    {
        int poolSize = 2;
        int maxPoolSize = 6;
        int threadPoolKeepAliveTimeInSec = 30;
        ExecutorService threadPoolExecutor =
                new MySimpleThreadPoolExecutor2(poolSize, maxPoolSize, threadPoolKeepAliveTimeInSec);
        int numOfThread = 5;
        System.out.println("Start thread pool test with corePoolSize=" + poolSize + ", maxPoolSize=" + maxPoolSize
                + ", actualThreads=" + numOfThread);
        for (int i = 0; i < numOfThread; i++)
        {
            MyRunnable tempRunnable = new MyRunnable(i + 1, "PoolTest" + (i + 1));
            myRunnables.add(tempRunnable);
            threadPoolExecutor.execute(tempRunnable);
        }
        System.out.println("********* wait for a while");
        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(20000);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("^^^^^^^^^^ shutdown them all");
        for (MyRunnable runnable : myRunnables)
        {
            runnable.shutdown();
        }
        System.out.println("Ended thread pool test.");

        System.exit(0);
    }

    public class MyRunnable implements Runnable
    {
        private int id = 0;
        private String name = "";

        private boolean shutdown = false;

        public MyRunnable(int id, String name)
        {
            this.id = id;
            this.name = name;
        }

        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            System.out.println("++++ Starting Thread: " + id + ":" + name);
            while (!shutdown)
            {
                try
                {
                    Thread.sleep(200);
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            System.out.println("---- Ended Thread: " + id + ":" + name);
        }

        public void shutdown()
        {
            shutdown = true;
        }
    }
}

class MySimpleThreadPoolExecutor2 extends ThreadPoolExecutor
{
    private static int peakActiveThreads = 0;
    private String taskInfo = "";

    public MySimpleThreadPoolExecutor2(int nThreads, int maxThreads, int threadPoolKeepAliveTimeInSec)
    {
        super(nThreads, maxThreads, threadPoolKeepAliveTimeInSec * 1000L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,
                new SynchronousQueue<Runnable>());
        System.out.println("MySimpleThreadPoolExecutor::MySimpleThreadPoolExecutor(), threadPoolSize=" + nThreads
                + ", maxThreadCount=" + maxThreads + ", threadPoolKeepAliveTimeInSec=" + threadPoolKeepAliveTimeInSec);
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeExecute(Thread t, Runnable r)
    {
        int activeCount = getActiveCount();
        if (MySimpleThreadPoolExecutor2.peakActiveThreads < activeCount)
        {
            MySimpleThreadPoolExecutor2.peakActiveThreads = activeCount;
        }
        taskInfo = r.toString();
        String msg =
                "BeforeE thread(name:id)::" + t.getName() + ":" + t.getId() + ", task::" + r.toString() + "\n"
                        + threadPoolInfoStr();
        System.out.println("ThreadInfo before, MySimpleThreadPoolExecutor::beforeExecute(), " + msg);
        super.beforeExecute(t, r);
    }

    @Override
    public void execute(Runnable command)
    {
        beforeExecute(Thread.currentThread(), command);
        super.execute(command);
    }

    public String threadPoolInfoStr()
    {
        return String
                .format("----------Thead: %s/%d\n[PoolSize/CorePoolSize] [%d/%d]\nActive: %d\nCompleted: %d\nTask: %d"
                        + "\nisShutdown: %s\nisTerminated: %s\npeakActiveThreads: %d\nTaskInfo: %s\nQueueSize: %d----------",
                        Thread.currentThread().getName(), Thread.currentThread().getId(), getPoolSize(),
                        getCorePoolSize(), getActiveCount(), getCompletedTaskCount(), getTaskCount(), isShutdown(),
                        isTerminated(), MySimpleThreadPoolExecutor2.peakActiveThreads, taskInfo, getQueue().size());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you explicitly call beforeExecute from the overridden execute() method in your subclass :

```
@Override
public void execute(Runnable command)
{
    beforeExecute(Thread.currentThread(), command);
    super.execute(command);
}
```

As the execute method is called from the client thread (in your case the main thread) it prints out an entry for the calling thread too. The super class however calls the `beforeExecute` method from its worker thread, prior to executing a submitted task.

Note the [javadoc for `beforeExecute`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#beforeExecute-java.lang.Thread-java.lang.Runnable-) :

> Method invoked prior to executing the given Runnable in the given thread. This method is invoked by thread t that will execute task r, and may be used to re-initialize ThreadLocals, or to perform logging.

Your explicit invocation from `execute()` is an extra invocation from the calling thread.

Answer (score -1):

*I am wondering why the main thread calls the customized ThreadPoolExecutor's execute() method?*

because it is explicitely called in the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new MyThreadPoolExecutorTest2().test();
}

public void test() {
   ...
   threadPoolExecutor = new MySimpleThreadPoolExecutor2();
   ...
       threadPoolExecutor.execute(tempRunnable);
                          ^^^^^^^
   ...
}
```

Comment: when downvoting, one should explain his attitude.